# Android Studio Problems:Red Squiggly Lines Under Modules, No Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm brand new to Android Studio and I've been having some problems getting it up and running. Have been working on this for the last 3 days alone with not much progress. When I launch a new project, no emulator appears and there are red squiggly lines under all of the modules. Here is a pic hosted on imgur:

https://i.imgur.com/P5I2DIO.jpg

I haven't been able to find any articles on these problems and none of the tutorials I've watched have said anything about extra steps to resolve them. 
I am posting them as a conjoined question because I suspect they are related problems. Thanks in advance for any guidance!

Comment: It looks like your.packagename.R wasn't imported.  Try that.  If it still doesn't work, try a build->clean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Red squiggly lines" indicate errors in your code. In this case, there's a problem with your R file. This is a file that Android generates to assign IDs to your resources.

Problems with the R file can be a number of things.

First, try:

```
Build -> Clean Project
```

---

*If that doesn't work:*

Make sure you have imported the R file of your project in the Java file of your activity. Try building the project to generate it.

---

*If that doesn't work (this one is worth remembering):*

There might be an error in one of your XML files. Look in the *res* folder and look for errors (red squiggly lines ;)!) in any of the files in the subfolders, fix any of these and the problem should resolve itself when R is regenerated.

Comment: Thanks for the response! The thing is, I haven't been able to actually write any code yet. Those lines aren't appearing in my code, they are appearing in the project structure names that AS generates. What I'm trying to find out is how to get to the point where I can actually do a simple "Hello World"  test.

Comment: It has created some starting code for you, though. Android Studio has generated a sample project for you to get started. That file open in your screenshot is a Java file of code. You need to expand the application folder (not sure which of the two it is from your screenshot), you should see a "res" folder, which has subfolders and files. If the first two options in my answer didn't do anything, you'll need to look through those files for errors.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Do you have any idea why the emulator is not showing up?

Comment: Just want to say that I tried your suggestions and the emulator is actually up and running now!  A few of the squiggly lines are still there, but this is great progress for me!

Comment: Thanks for copying my answer. -1

Comment: @KarenForde I never edited my post. Your first and second step is the same exact as mine. thus you shouldn't have posted the 3 of them but the only one that wasn't a pure copy, therefor it should be a comment on my post.

Comment: @AbAppletic Sorry, I mixed you up with Abishek below when I wrote the comments and just realised that and deleted the comments before you wrote back - I actually wrote my answer 19 hours ago, you wrote yours 15 hours ago. Mine was here first so I literally couldn't have copied you. That''s why I mixed you up with the other answer too, I didn't see one with both clean and import. I'm not going to blame you for copying mine either, because I assume you didn't downvote me for the fun of it and did think it was a copy,you presumably missed mine the first time. I'd appreciate removing the downvote.

Comment: @KarenForde Aah, sorry, my bad. I overreact a lot of times :P

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me twice. Both because of mess in resources. No playing with
`caches invalidate` gave result.

**So:**

First time when I looked into resource folders within *File Explorer* ... there were folders inside *drawable* folder!
Second time the layouts and strings xmls had wrong symbols when I imported the project in other encoding.

When first time, it showed **app**  as red underlined one only. No caution no hint. And didnt point to any error and IDE builded aabs just ok

Comment: I noticed this on mine! They seemed to have put themselves in some sort of "Drawable-v24" folder. I simple hit refactor > move file. I moved them back to Drawable. I'm curious what this "v24" was, though.

Comment: @Mark Puchala II
 I think that is a matter of case if the app has been succeeded. For kind of screen sizes dencities and else headaches . Initially I also used to dump all the stuff to the plain drawable folder

Comment: For me, there is a redundant folder in resources/color folder. I just delete it.
Try to open the resources file in File Explorer and seek for a redundant file if you didn't find the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you go to `Build > Clean Project`, you'll have a high possibility of fixing this.

---

Otherwise, go to `File> Invalidate Caches/Restart` and see what happens.

---

What can also be the problem is a missing `import` statement. Highlight `R` and press `ALT+ENTER`. If there is an "Import Class" Option, click that.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when running the project with another user profile on windows.
What solved to me was set the ndk path to the rigth paths.

from 
C:\Users\XXXXXXX\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle

to
C:\Users\YYYYYYY\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

After cleaning and rebuilding the project, if the squiggly line is still there, close and reload the project.

Answer (score 1):

Can be invalid characters in file name, my file has "-" and ".", for example "a-b.c.d.e-f.g" filename in raw will cause this

Answer (score 0):

Problem is due to R file.
Try cleaning the project.
`Build > Clean Project`

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:**
In my case I had added a hollow folder in SRC. When I add a hollow folder, the folder still does not appear Android studio 2022/12. To realize the situation, we opened the Project view instead of Android and the error showed itself. **I deleted the extra folder.** (error gone)

**Step 2:**
In Android view:
App right click /
**Optimize Imports**
The underlined app Java import error is gone.

Also, doing a quick scan and reading the suggestions on this page led to this idea. Thank you to all the commenters.

Answer (score -2):

My androidstudio does the same exact thing. It really dosent mean anything. It's just android studio detecting a spelling error. It dosent mean anything so you don't have to worry.

Comment: Thanks for the response! The only thing that concerns me is that you some of those words are spelled correctly if you look at the screenshot.However, I can live with squiggly lines. The bigger issue is that I haven't been able to launch a project since downloading AS 3 days ago. Any ideas why the emulator doesn't show up?

Comment: The emulator that comes with AS can be very bad, I recommend using the Genymotion emulator. It runs smoothly and has a plugin built into AS. Just google genymotion, its very easy to install.

Comment: Very very bad answer. "Red Squigly Lines" means there's an error.